# Can the 'default native GSS-API on Windows' in Java 12 support SSO with JAAS by using the Krb5 principal of the user executing the JVM?

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, jaas, jgss

### Vanilla Krb5LoginModule is working, prompting for creds

In my modest usage of `JAAS -> JGSS -> Kerberos -> Windows` thus far, I have set up a `Krb5LoginModule` When I do:

```
Subject.doAs(
    new LoginContext(...)).login(),  // subject
    new MyPrivilegedAction()         // action
)
```

... I am prompted for credentials, and the action is successful.

### Using TGT Session Key hack, can avoid prompt for creds

If I also add `useTicketCache=true` to the login module, and if I put up with the security hazards of setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters\AllowTgtSessionKey=1` and don't use Windows 10 Credential Guard, then the action is successful *without* a prompt for credentials.

### Java 12 gives us a default native GSS-API lib even on Windows

Java 11.0.10 [introduced](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-6722928) the possibility of [using a native GSS-API implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/accessing-native-gss-api.html) on Windows but did not provide a default implementation.  Java 12 [added a native implementation of GSS-API](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210801) which bridged to the Windows SSPI.  This avoids the need for the risky `AllowTGTSessionKey`.

### Using native GSS-API works too, prompting for creds

On Java 15.0.2 (both Oracle and OpenJDK) on Windows, *despite* the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/security/accessing-native-gss-api.html)) still (now incorrectly) claiming, "There is no well-known native GSS-API library on Windows", I can:

- Omit `java.security.krb5.realm` and `java.security.krb5.kd` system properties (which I use in lieu of a full-blown kr5.conf, since my AD environment is simple); and
- merely specify `sun.security.jgss.native=true`.

... and the action *prompts for credentials*, but is successful.

### But native always prompts for credentials

Can I expect when using `sun.security.jgss.native=true` (on JDK 15.0.2 on Windows) that `JAAS -> JGSS -> Kerberos -> Windows` will attempt to use the Windows LSASS via the SSPI to obtain the credentials of the user executing the JVM?  Or is this not something that the native `GSS-API -> SSPI` library facilitates?  Information is thin on the ground!

Comment: When the JAAS `CallbackHandler` is invoked using native, it does correctly suggest my username ... it just isn't fetching my password from Windows the way it does when using pure-Java with the `AllowTGTSessionKey` hack.

Comment: I feel like there are probably 4 people in the world who could answer this, and they're all really busy.

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you tweak the default JAAS configuration in your tests? and did you check what JAAS makes of its config via `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` or sthg similar?

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter I can confirm the intended file is being parsed.  I think I will chug along with the tutorials and try to make a minimal repro with just GSS-API and leave JAAS out of it.  Will update the Qn when I have more info.

Comment: Any news on this topic?

Comment: @fjf2002 I did not chase it to the end of the line yet.  For me, the bigger picture was to allow my Java app-server to transparently propagate the identity of the user-agent all the way to the DBMS.  But the whole attention of the industry is on OAuth now, and not on this scenario.  I will take another look at things when JDK17 ships (not too long now!)